# Puzzle with FileWriter in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, io, filewriter

I have Groovy code like this...

```
class GuiWindow extends SwingBuilder {

....
FileWriter writer

    GuiWindow(def controller)
{
    ....
    writer = new FileWriter("DATA${new Date().time.toString()}.txt")
    writer.write("Count, Rate\n")
```

This code successfully creates the file but seemingly refuses to write anything into it - not even the header line of text in the immediate next statement.

I have used very similar code before without any problem so am at a bit of a loss as to know what is wrong.

I don't `close()` the writer - it is meant to be open to record data which comes in slowly - so the one thing I can think of is that the writing is batched and only written when a buffer overflows - but can someone tell me what is wrong with my code or why it doesn't behave the way I expect it to?

Comment: I assume you've tried adding `writer.flush()` after your write to show that you're probably right about the buffering

Comment: Don't you like Groovy operator `<<` ;)   Try that: `def out= new File('text_from_groovy.txt');
out.createNewFile();
out << 'your text';`

Comment: @olyv that will open a writer append and close it each time, which can get expensive if you do it a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like tim_yates mentiones above, **flush** solved the problem in my case.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("DATA${new Date().time.toString()}.txt")
writer.write("Count, Rate\n")
writer.flush()
```